# I need to make an event happen on my website if a button has been clicked x times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make an invisible section on my website that will expand after a buttton has been clicked x times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have what you are asking for.

Working Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/KingPineapple/dqa08jo5/46/

HTML:

```
<div id='hidden-div'>
Hello
</div>
<span id='show-count'>0</span>
<button onClick=(toggleDiv())>
Click me
</button>
```

CSS:

```
    #hidden-div{
       border:1px solid black;
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       width:0;
       height:200px;
    }
    .show-div{
      animation: 2s showDiv forwards;
    }
    @keyframes showDiv {
     from{width:0;}
     to{width:400px;}
    }
```

JS:

```
    let count = 0;
    let showOn = 10;
    toggleDiv = () => {
    if(count < showOn -1 ){
    count++
    document.getElementById("show-count").innerHTML = count;
    document.getElementById('hidden-div').classList.remove("show-div")
    return
    }
    document.getElementById('hidden-div').classList.add("show-div")
    count = 0;
    }
```